# Placeholders in my component doesn't show in Sitecore connected mode after a deploy - JSS - vueJs

Tags: jss

*As a* developer,
*I want* my placeholder to be rendered in sitecore,
*so that* I can add more components inside

First of all, in disconnected mode, everything is fine:

1 - I have a placeholder named : **PH__fullscreen-hero** inside my component:

[image: fullscreen-hero.vue]

2 - I added data to my en.json:

[image: en.json]

3 - In local mode, everything is fine:

[image: local]

4 - Then after : `jss deploy package -c -d`

5 - in connected mode in my sitecore all placeholders are created nevertheless PH__fullscreen-hero doesn't render in the DOM in Experience Editor... :

[image]

Did I forget something ?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's the fact this file doesn't exist in the vue sample : 
[placeholders.sitecore.js](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/master/samples/basic-sample-react/sitecore/definitions/placeholders.sitecore.js)

Comment: It will exist in the next version's Vue sample :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

I forgot to include Placeholder in \sitecore\definitions\components\FullscreenHero.sitecore.js

[image]